# Ubuntu: how to fix a deeply broken apt?

Tags: apt, virtualbox, dpkg

I'm running Kubuntu 23.10 and I recently tried to install virtualbox 7.0 from the oracle website. After executing `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb` nothing happened. I waited some hours without any success. After aprooximately 3 hours I broke dpkg. I know that this is not recommended to be done but, what should I do else if dpkg is simply doing nothing including no error messages. Even the CPU is not busy.

Since this event it seems totally corrupt. Nothing works. Trying to install anything such like `sudo apt install --reinstall nano` (just to check if it basically works) leads to a message that virtualbox-7.0 needs to be reconfigured but there is no archive for it, sadly.
Orifinal text (Dutch):

```
E: Pakket virtualbox-7.0 moet opnieuw geïnstalleerd worden, maar er kan geen archief voor gevonden worden.
```

Even a `virtualbox-7.0 (7.0.12-159484~Ubuntu~jammy) wordt verwijderd ...`
down't work. Again, there is no error message. It simply does nothing. Original text (Dutch):

```
virtualbox-7.0 (7.0.12-159484~Ubuntu~jammy) wordt verwijderd ...
```

Even after hours and hours of useless waiting nothing happens. No errors. No success. Pure silence.

I'm a kind of desperate since I have a dpkg which doesn't even return errors to but, that simply doesn't to what it's told to do.

How can I manually manipulate package on a config file level configuration in order to get a working system again? Maybe this is not recommended normally but, with that said I don't see any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to uninstall virtualbox:

```
dpkg -r virtualbox-7.0
```

Also you could try to start the configuration manually:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```